# HTML Canvas and memory usage

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, canvas, cropperjs

I'm making a very basic image editor for mobile using the canvas and cordova.
Unfortunately, javascript is a pig for memory when the canvas is involved, this causes everything to crash outright on mobile.

I am using cropperjs to handle the cropping. (If you have a better one, please let me know).  Cropper only allows images to be retrieved by using base 64 data URLs, which appear to be huge memory wasters.
Once the image is cropped, I need to redisplay it for cropping again.
A bonus is the image is being turned to black and white based on how it was cropped.  That part is working very well, but again doubles the memory size probably since it's ultimately using dataURLs extracted from a canvas.

A button on the page calls this function. This is where the trouble seems to get started.

```
var originalImage = document.createElement('img');
var cropper;
    function finish() {            
        var data=cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
        originalImage.onload = function () {
            cropper.replace(originalImage, false);
            cropper.clear();
            originalImage.onload=undefined;
        };
        originalImage.src=data;

    }
```

I am guessing the ultimate issue is that the dataURL is so massive, even when not in the DOM it burns memory.  This little bit of code causes chrome and firefox to add around 700mb of RAM usage for 600kb photo.
Is there a better way to store modified images in memory? Something smaller? Or alternatively, is there a way to make a new temp file and load that? Or am I on the wrong track entirely?

-Edits for Blindman67's answer

```
const originalImage = document.createElement('canvas');
originalImage.ctx = originalImage.getContext("2d");
var cropper; //cropper is created and destroyed on image load, so I can't use const?
function finish() {                
    const cropped = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
    originalImage.width = cropped.width;
    originalImage.height = cropped.height;
    originalImage.ctx.drawImage(cropped,0,0);
    cropper.clear();
    cropper.replace(originalImage , false); //errors, TypeError: t.match is not a function, cropper.min.js (line 11, col 4244)
}
```

Code that loads the image from a file upload

```
    $('#file').on('change', function (ev) {            
        var f = ev.target.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader();

        fr.onload = function (ev2) {
            console.dir(ev2);
            if (cropper !== undefined) {
                cropper.destroy();
            }

            //Probably something wrong with this part
            $('#img').on("load",function(){
                originalImage.width = this.width;
                originalImage.height = this.height;
                originalImage.ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("img"),0,0);
            }).attr('src', ev2.target.result);
            //^^^^^

            //obvious I've been at this awhile, efficiency went down the tubes \/
            var image = document.getElementById("img");
            var options = {
                viewMode: 0,
                dragMode: 'crop',
                responsive: true,
                autoCrop: false,
                movable: false,
                scalable: false,
                zoomable: false,
                zoomOnTouch: false,
                zoomOnWheel: false,
                ready: cropReady
            };
            cropper = new Cropper(image, options);
        };

        fr.readAsDataURL(f);
    });
```

The page itself is basically

```
<div >
    <img id="img" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%"/>
</div>
```

-Edit
It looks like using canvases instead of imgs works well enough.

html:

```
<div class="span-filler">
    <img id="img" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 650px"/>
    <canvas id="originalImg" style="display:none;max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;">Please use Chrome or Firefox
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Scripts

```
var cropper;
var gBrightness = 0;
var orgImg = document.getElementById("originalImg");
function finish() {
    cropper.replace(orgImg, true); //doesn't need to data URL oddly
    var data = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
    orgImg.width = data.width;
    orgImg.height = data.height;
    orgImg.getContext("2d").drawImage(data, 0, 0);
    cropper.replace(orgImg.toDataURL("Image/jpeg"), false); //does need it
    cropper.clear();
}
$('#file').on('change', function (ev) {
    var f = ev.target.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();

    fr.onload = function (ev2) {
        console.dir(ev2);
        if (cropper !== undefined) {
            cropper.destroy();
        }
        $('#img').attr('src', ev2.target.result);
        var image = document.getElementById("img");
        var options = {
            viewMode: 0,
            dragMode: 'crop',
            responsive: true,
            autoCrop: false,
            movable: false,
            scalable: false,
            zoomable: false,
            zoomOnTouch: false,
            zoomOnWheel: false,
            ready: cropReady
        };
        cropper = new Cropper(image, options);
    };

    fr.readAsDataURL(f);
});
function cropReady() {

    var data = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
    orgImg.width = data.width;
    orgImg.height = data.height;
    orgImg.getContext("2d").drawImage(data, 0, 0);

    processImage(); //converts to black and white using web workers
}

//still looking for efficiencies here
function processImage(brightness) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = orgImg.width;
    canvas.height = orgImg.height;

    var imgPixels;
    var imgPixelsSrc = orgImg.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, orgImg.width, orgImg.height);


    var myWorker = new Worker('js/image_editor/imageWorker.js');

    myWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
        imgPixels = e.data[0];
        gBrightness = e.data[2];

        ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0);
        cropper.replace(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), true);
    };
    if (brightness === undefined) {
        myWorker.postMessage([imgPixelsSrc, true]);
    } else {
        myWorker.postMessage([imgPixelsSrc, false, brightness]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this line have no sense : originalImage.onload=undefined; also : cropper.replace . Please publish code snippet if is possible ! Use simple canvas to crop part of image . You can collect image data look at : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp

Comment: I don't find anything obvious when I search "simple canvas". I am using this presently, but am willing to switch to another if there is a better one. https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs. `cropper.replace(originalImage, false);` takes an htmlimage as the first parameter, and update colour or full as the second, true for colour only, false for reload. Since in theory the image has changed size, it needs to reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas can be used as an image and is a HTML image element. There is no need to convert from a canvas to an image just to display the results.

```
const originalImage = document.createElement('canvas');
originalImage.ctx = originalImage.getContext("2d");
const cropper;
function finish() {            
    // check documentation to ensure cropper
    // is not creating a copy but rather
    // is returning just a reference
    const cropped = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();        
    originalImage.width = cropped.width;
    originalImage.height = cropped.height;
    originalImage.ctx.drawImage(cropped,0,0);
    cropper.clear();
}
```

Comment: It took a bit to make these edits but, `cropper.replace(originalImage , true);` throws `TypeError: t.match is not a function` from cropper.min.js.

Comment: HTMLCanvasElement is not an HTMLImageElement. It's not because both  objects can be passed to `drawImage` that they're the same...

Comment: If I stored the dataurl in sessionStorage and only gave it to in memory image variables just long enough to load the cropper, then clear it. Would that help? Or localStorage? Or would both cause the same issue?

Comment: @TrevorD you won't have the room, on mobiles the storage is very small. I dont understand what the problem is. You say cropper.replace is throwing an error, why are you using it. You have the cropped image as a canvas, you should just destroy the cropper object and display the canvas. if you want the client to recrop then just restart.

Comment: Well yeah, restarting is basically what I am doing. But to restart it, it has to move from the canvas to an image, then back to cropper, causing the memory bloat.  Some of the code does help though.  I can use this trick in another location where the crop operation only happens once. I imagine ultimately I will have to use this and create temp files. http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/150/how-to-create-an-image-file-from-a-base64-string-on-the-device-with-cordova

Comment: @TrevorD In the document (readme.md at github) it states that the cropper can be created from a canvas "Wrap the image or **canvas** element with a block element (container)" Also the API is sloppy and exposes the canvas it uses so you could just change it directly rather than via its interface. When you have a problem with a library you should always go past (after reading) the documentation and look at the code.

Comment: Oh, so if I wrap the canvas in a div it might be happy? Thanks I will try that as soon as I can.

Comment: Ok, it was a little harder than just giving it the canvas, but memory no longer explodes to a gig for a single image, but now only 200mb on average. So very nice!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var img = new Image();
//img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
  draw(this);
};

function draw(img) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  img.style.display = 'none';
  window['zoomCanvas'] = document.getElementById('zoom');
  window['zoomctx'] = document.getElementById('zoom').getContext('2d');
 
  var smoothbtn = document.getElementById('smoothbtn');
  var toggleSmoothing = function(event) {
    zoomctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = this.checked;
    zoomctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = this.checked;
    zoomctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = this.checked;
    zoomctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = this.checked;
  };
  
  
  smoothbtn.addEventListener('change', toggleSmoothing);

  var zoom = function(event) {
    var x = event.layerX;
    var y = event.layerY;
    zoomctx.drawImage(canvas,
                      Math.abs(x - 100),
                      Math.abs(y - 100),
                      200, 200,
                      0, 0,
                      200, 200);
  };

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', zoom);
  
  
  function CROP_IT (e){
  
  //this line  will collect  all data from canvas 
  window["IMAGE_CROPED"] = zoomCanvas.toDataURL();
   localStorage.setItem( "savedImageData", zoomCanvas.toDataURL("image/png") );
   
  alert(IMAGE_CROPED)
  
  } 
  
  canvas.addEventListener('click', CROP_IT , false);
  
  
  
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas -->

<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="227"></canvas>
<canvas id="zoom" width="300" height="227"></canvas>
<div>
<label for="smoothbtn">
  <input type="checkbox" name="smoothbtn" checked="false" id="smoothbtn">
  Enable image smoothing
</label>
```

Comment: Although not exactly what I need since this page is essentially for taking pictures of documents, so it needs a precise crop. It's still quite interesting and might help me in other spots.  So thanks :)